# Getting Text or Graphic object X,Y coordinate in ITextPDF

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to use ITextPDF 5.5.x in java to populate the form fields automatically.   My question is that how do I get the X, Y coordinates of the graphic lines so I can use it as the coordinate for TextField, RadioButton, CheckButton?

i.e.

```
Name: _________________
[] option1
[] option2
```

How do find the x-y coordinate, dimension of line and the rectangular in the above PDF so that I can add the textfield, etc. with the coordinates accordingly ?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you talking about a form or about an ordinary PDF. A form involves form fields. Form fields can be filled out without the need to get the coordinates.

Comment: I meant from an ordinary PDF, my program will add form fields to it to make it a PDF with form fields in it.

Comment: In an *ordinary PDF* (I assume you thereby mean a pdf without a formal - AcroForm or XFA - form definition) there is no common (let alone standard) way form elements are represented. Thus, I think you will be surprised by the extent of your task. That been said you can identify vector graphics paths (which may form lines or squares or...) using a `RenderListenerExt` implementation and bitmap images (which may display form elements, too) using an implementation of the underlying `RenderListener` methods.